# Python how to optimize map function to handle huge data without reaching 100% CPU

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate over range of large numbers and perform a small calculation. But my CPU is reaching 100% until the execution is done. Can someone suggest me how to optimize this or let me know if any better approach can be done. My hardware is windows10,4core CPU,8GB RAM.

```
from functools import partial


def using_map_function(number, name):
    print("number square is {} and repo_name is {}".format(number * number, name))

def using_range(numbers, name):
    for number in numbers:
        print("number square is {} and repo_name is {}".format(number * number, name))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # mapFunc = partial(using_map_function, name="Hello")
    # map(mapFunc, range(500000))
    using_range(numbers=range(500000),name="Hello")
```

Comment: what's wrong with 100% of cpu being used?  .... to slow it down, you can add a sleep in your loop.

Comment: I thought that introducing sleep will increase the script execution time, so I didn't try with sleep.

Comment: of course it will

Comment: you are basically asking "how do I slow my program down without slowing it down"

Comment: my aim is to reduce the cpu usage without reducing the execution time

Comment: why do you want to decrease cpu usage?

Comment: if you want to do some other tasks while running this large query, you can try to limit the CPU usage for Python

Answer (score 0):

Using the `print()` function wastes a lot of time for processing, you can try to remove them when you're sure your code is running well.
You can also have a lot at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103367/limit-total-cpu-usage-in-python-multiprocessing) in order to try limitating the CPU usage of your python script.