# How to limit the CPU usage of pool.map in multiprocessing module?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Note: Already used this
[Limit total CPU usage in python multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103367/limit-total-cpu-usage-in-python-multiprocessing) as a reference.

I have some 200 files of Excel sum of rows is equals to nearly 30k records.
So for an efficient solution used `multiprocessing.pool` method.

Sample code here:

```
def MainFunction(eachFile):
    #all the process/operations happening here takes some 25 secs using pandas,numpy...

pool = Pool(maxtasksperchild=1)
s=pool.map(MainFunction, MainListFiles)
pool.close()
pool.join()
del pool
pool=None
```

The above code Consumes fro 30k rows around 475% of CPU.
The above code Consumes fro 20k rows around 290% of CPU.
The above code Consumes fro 10k rows around 150% of CPU.

So here number of rows I directly proportional to CPU Usage.

Which is deployed in Pivotal cloud foundry, Where other components also running using `multiprocessing`. It's highly stressing the cpu of the instance. So the container crashes every time, and the only possible fix is **Limitting or controlling the cpu---so it won't increase more than 250%**.

Stuff I've tried:

1. **Using `time.sleep()`**

   Split into two lists and put `sleep` for 15 secs between two process. But no luck.

   ```
   List1 = MainListFiles[:len(MainListFiles)//2]
   List2 = MainListFiles[len(MainListFiles)//2:]
   pool = Pool(maxtasksperchild=1)
   s=pool.map(MainFunction, List1)
   time.sleep(15)
   s1=pool.map(MainFunction, List2)
   pool.close()
   pool.join()
   del pool
   pool=None
   ```
2. Used **`multiprocessing.Process()`** method also from `multiprocessing` module. No luck. Cpu gone to 400%.

   ```
   for files in  MainListFiles:
       s=multiprocessing.Process(target=multiprocessing_func,args=(files,))
       processes.append(s)
       s.start()
   for process in processes:
       process.join()
   ```
3. Tried with `pool(processes=os.cpu_count()//2)`

   **No effect---Time elapsed more and cpu still in peak**

Please advise me how to can control the cpu on `.map()` in `multiprocessing`, or any other method will work like queue or pipe?

Comment: Use `Pool(processes=n)` where `n` is some number less than `os.cpu_count()`

Comment: Tried Already no luck gave 4 instead 8 processes.

Comment: Have you tried ``Pool(processes=n)`` with an actual fixed ``n`` instead of e.g. ``os.cpu_count()//2``? Are you certain that ``os.cpu_count()`` returns the number of cores *accessible to you* (i.e. the container), not the entire system outside of the container?

Comment: See also [BPO 36054: On Linux, os.count() should read cgroup cpu.shares and cpu.cfs (CPU count inside docker container)](https://bugs.python.org/issue36054)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Tried with pool(processes=4) available cores is total 8 cores in a container.But no luck still cpu is % is more but i can see that timetaken for execution is more.