# VM Shutdown in GCP because of 100% CPU Usage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, multiprocessing, virtual-machine, cpu-usage

I am running a CPU intensive job in GCP with VM - `c2-standard-16`

The batch job runs daily with cron schedule.
It runs a facematch algorithm using tensorflow for many students folder in parallel.
I am making use of multiprocessing to parallel process the request.
The output of which is written to a CSV file, and put into BigQuery.

```
  loop each topic :
  multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
  pool = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
```

Also, it runs for n number of topics, so n-topics(say 10) x n-student (say 200-3000+) folders needs to be processed.

```
result = pool.map(self.process_student, folders, chunksize=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.to_csv(csv_report_name, index=False)
```

The script works fine for 200 student folder, When it comes to 2000 and above student folders, it stop after processing about 400 students.(as i see in the log) the script shuts down abruptly the process and the VM is non-responsive. SSH connections are broken.
Doing a `top` show while in run CPU Usage is show as 100% or above.

All cores are utilised >100%

Tried so far

- Divide the folders into chunk of 200 and introduced a sleep time of 10 mins, to throttle down the CPU usage. (works for 2-3 chunks) and stops again.
- added a delay of mill-seconds, in the parallel process  method -> self.process_student
- Choose half of the cores from available cores to multi-process. (Half of the Cores will still throttle to 100% and above.)
  The CPU usage quota is not editable, CPU usage quota is full.

Tried all the guide
[Limit total CPU usage in python multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103367/limit-total-cpu-usage-in-python-multiprocessing)
None worked. Please help.

Comment: Review the stats for memory usage and disk swapping. If memory usage is too high, your option is to select a larger VM. If the system is swapping memory to disk, then you must select a larger instance size. A quick test is to resize larger and test again. You can resize smaller after the tests.

Comment: Any luck with resizing VM ?

Comment: I tried resizing the VM, to 32 gigs of RAM, the same issue. Cant scale higher than it.

Comment: What's the [CPU utilisation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/cpu-utilization) in Cloud Monitoring ? Can you provide some more logs ?